# fetch data from form-data nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
form.append('location', location);
form.append('name', nameList); 
form.submit('/', function(err, res) {
    console.log("upload_files")
    console.log("************")

    console.log(res)
    if (err) {
      return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('file_upload:',res.statusCode)

      if(res.statusCode == 200){

        files.forEach(function (file, index) {
          counter +=1}
    }
   }
```

**when i use this code i get response from server but can't i fetch the data
 how i can parse for data come from server**

Comment: what do you see in 'console.error' vs 'console.log', also, have you observed the network tab in your browser?

Comment: IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     read

Comment: I GET this response and more how i can get data from his response